# How can I make a hole in this mesh and not mess it up?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm a bit new in Blender and this strange problem came out and I can't solve it:

So, I have this mesh and I wanted to put some holes in it, like this:
[image]

I've used a lot of ways but everytime I do a hole, it appears complete messed up (in this case, I used a boolean modifier):[image]

Hopefully, I can get some help!

Comment: This looks like good use case for Bezier Curve objects instead, if you don't need a clean topology later down the road. Though you might have to be careful with the bevel sizes so they don't cause self intersections with the outer edges.

Comment: I'm really really new at this and all you said didn't really made sense to me... I'm thankfull for your help but could you explain me a little better what you said? @DuarteFarrajotaRamos

Comment: See my answer bellow for more detail

Comment: So that means I'll have to do that again in order to make the holes like you did on the gif, right? And what if I want to export to some later game or texturing/nodes, can I retropology the blade if I make it with Bezier Curves? @DuarteFarrajotaRamos

Comment: Yes, to use bezier curves you would have to start from scratch. Yes, you should be able to retopologize with the modifier for texturing or export purposes without major problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a good candidate for Bezier curve objects.

It looks like you modeled you "blade" as a mesh object, there is nothing inherently wrong with it, but what you are trying to achieve may be a lot eaiser to do with [Bezier Curve objects](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/curves/introduction.html)

They describe mathematical curves controlled by handles, instead of vertex, edges, and faces like meshes.

Since you don't have to actively worry about topology or "filling" in the faces they are very easy to use for opening holes like you want.

[image: Bezier curve]

They will however require that you start to model from scratch using a diferent object.

Have in mind that they may not be useful depending on what you intend to use your object for later. If you plan on doing heavy texturing work involving unwrapping your mesh, shape animations, rigging, or plan to export this into a game engine; the topology produced by Bezier Curve Objects may not be adequate.

Otherwise you may also do this using meshes. Whether using [Booleans (not recommended)](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html) or manually modelling it, but it will require lots of work and [good understanding of proper topology](http://topologyguides.com/).