# Little fails in retopology

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I had a mesh in which I wanted to do some retopology to add some holes in it.
Altough I did retopology the mesh, some strange failures happened.

How can I fix those fails? And also, after I've done this, can I add holes without having any glitches of some kind?

Edit Mode:
Original[image]
Retopology[image]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your mesh in *Edit Mode*.

Comment: Done @PaulGonet

Comment: What "glitches" are you referring to?

Comment: @pycoder Everytime I did a hole in it, some "phantom" face appeared above it. I made a question about it. [link](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76722/how-can-i-make-a-hole-in-this-mesh-and-not-mess-it-up)

Comment: Can you indicate the glitches that you are concerned about in an image in Edit Mode? Could you describe them a little more?

Comment: Yep, I seen no obvious glitches, could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @Sazerac Here's the glitches I'm talking about. Keep in mind this is the old mesh, not the retopologised one http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76722/how-can-i-make-a-hole-in-this-mesh-and-not-mess-it-up

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos You were the one who answered me to the previous question, you said it was a good bevel circle case. But you mentioned topology in which I had the ideia of the topology being wrong, so I retopologised it and tried again, but the same glitchy face appears. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76722/how-can-i-make-a-hole-in-this-mesh-and-not-mess-it-up

Comment: Your topology seems quite good, especially the fist one. What glitchy faces are you talking about, can you annotate a screenshot and mark which face is giving your trouble?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos In which question? This one or the linked one?

Comment: @DarkKool This one.