# Boolean Operation fails when using a joined cutting object

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects

I am trying to cut a slot into a flatten cubed. The slot was made with two cylinders and a cube which I joined. When I try to use the object as a cut piece it only seems to be using one of the cylinders and ignores the rest of the compound object.

On a side note my image clips when I zoom in.

Any ideas?

Screen shot

[image: failed Boolean cut]

Comment: Booleans are a lazy way of modeling, learn proper modelling techniques. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34451/how-to-cut-holes-in-an-object-using-another-object/34460#34460 , you can't use "compound objects" with self intersections in Booleans. Also decrease you viewport *Near Clipping* in the *Properties Toolshelf* `N` Key

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos what proper technique should i use? Can you forward a tutorial? I am new to blender.

Comment: [This may help](http://topologyguides.com), specifically the part about opening holes in a mesh . In your particular case modeling that piece with a *Bezier Curve Object* may also be easier see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76722/how-can-i-make-a-hole-in-this-mesh-and-not-mess-it-up/76725#76725 or try searching for [Bezier curve tutorials here on this site](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=bezier+curves) or over on Youtube.