# How can I model this Body in Blender?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, mesh, modifiers

Hello Blender Community,
I am new to Blender. In the past, I only used CAD Programs (Inventor, Fusion 360). Because of the Rendering and Animation, I try to recreate my models in Blender. One of my first projects would be this Keychain. (I already rendered it in Fusion 360).
[image]

First I tried to take a SVG file, convert it to a mesh and extrude it into the Z-axis. After that, I had really bad topology and I couldn't model proper chamfers.

On my second approach, I tried to model it with a Subdivision Surface modifier.  The result was better but still not really good.

[image]
[image]
How should I approach this Project? Can anybody give me a tip on how I should approach this task? What is the right way to model this in Blender?

Thank you very much, I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Multiple ways to achieve that... Since the surface is flat, I'd bring the 2d-shape into blender, extrude it and add a bevel modifier.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76722/how-can-i-make-a-hole-in-this-mesh-and-not-mess-it-up/76725#76725

Comment: @brockmann Thank you for the advice, but I have already tried that. The problem is that the 2D Surface is a SVG file. The SVG file consists of curves. When I make the curve into a mesh the topology only consists of triangles. Then when I extrude it is impossible to add a bevel and the surface doesn't look flat in the render. When the triangle topology is very dense it is somehow visible on the surface.

Comment: You just need the shape of the outline. For curves see the link Duarte posted 30min ago @LilBlend